# selectmenu ('refresh', true)

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, jquery-mobile, select-menu

I get form from zend framework site and put it in response in new file in function written by jquery mobile, but I get this error:

> uncaught exception: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' .

Code of function this file:

```
     function addItem(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://zf.darina.php.nixsolutions.com/order/index/create-order-mobile',
            dataType:"jsonp",
            data:{id_good:id},
            success:function (resp) {

                console.log(resp);
                $('.product-table').empty();

                $('.product-table').append(resp.prod);
                $('.product-table').append(resp.form);
                $('.add-order-btn').button();

                $('.mob-size').selectmenu('refresh', true);

                $('#block').page();
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you give details about this 'mob-size'. I believe this object is not initialized yet.

Comment: class Order_Form_MobileSize_Size extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $selSize = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('size', array("class" => "mob-size", 'id' => 'mob-size'));
        $AllSize = $orderModel->selectSize();
             foreach ($AllSize as $size){
            $options[$size['id']] = $size['size'];
        }
        $selSize->setLabel('Размер')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addMultioptions($options)
            ->setAttribs(array('style' => 'width:40%'));
        $this->addElement($selSize);
        return $this;
    }
}

Comment: I must refresh this form for get jquerymobile desigin for it

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Force initialize the selectmenu(s) first:

```
$('.mob-size').selectmenu(); // Initializes
$('.mob-size').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

or use this for short

```
$('.mob-size').selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: While this is the popular answer, it didn't work for my situation and I don't believe it will work for the OP either.  This is because the `$(".mob-size")` on it's own points to the select menu AND to a `<span>` element that JQM adds for the label. (ie. It passes the class on to the new elements it creates.) The label is NEVER initialized as a selectmenu, because it can't be!  Jim's solution to use `$("select.mob-size")` instead will ensure that you don't also select the label.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, if I was not initializing the select before invoking the 'disable' method I got the error, while if I was initializing it, the select didn't disable but duplicate itself - I tried to select the object by TAG NAME instead of by CLASS or ID NAME,

```
$('select').selectmenu('disable');
```

instead of

```
$('.select-class-name').selectmenu('disable');
```

and it worked without forced initialization

Comment: Sweet, thanks for this.  After experimenting, I found I could also use 
$('select.select-class-name') to do same fix in jqm 1.4.5.

Comment: @JimH., your comment ended up being the solution for me.  This is because the $(".select-class-name") on it's own points to the select menu AND a `<span>` element that JQM adds for the label.  (ie. It passes the class on to the new elements it creates.)  The label is NEVER initialized as a selectmenu, because it can't be!

Answer (score 4):

you do this in your custom refresh delegation function:

```
var w = $("#yourinput");
if( w.data("mobile-selectmenu") === undefined) {
  // not initialized yet, lets do so
  w.selectmenu();
}
w.selectmenu("refresh",true);
```

according to [enhancement resolution here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4746#issuecomment-10369891)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, but a more involved solution. When jqm wraps the `select` element, it puts it in a `<span>` element with the same class list as the `select` element. I changed my reference to it so that instead of reading:

```
row.find(".selectCompletion").selectmenu("disable");
```

it now reads:

```
row.find("select.selectCompletion").selectmenu("disable");
```

Specifying that jquery should only find the `select` element matching the class name, rather than all elements in .row that match the class name, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when **cloning** existing select element in order to **duplicate** the original section multiple times.

Calling '**refresh**' for the original element, worked fine, while calling it for the cloned sections was **leading to the error appearing in the question**.

However, calling **selectmenu()** was causing a 'vandalisation' to the form, as can be seen in the following image:

[image]

Explanation: top = original. bottom = vandalised cloned element right after calling selectmenu.

**Solution:**

The following code solved this vandalisation problem:

cloned_elem.find('select[name=MyClass]')**.selectmenu().selectmenu("destroy").selectmenu()**;

This is not an ideal solution because we must call the first selectmenu() in order to call selectmenu("destroy"), so I would be glad to hear of a cleaner solution.